# Would (Eclipse PDT == Zend Studio 8) return true?

Tags: php, ide, zend-studio, eclipse-pdt

Are they too much alike, totally different, neither?

Drawing from PHP-style comparison, this would return true even if they were basically the same but not *identical*. (Not ===)

Appreciate any insights please.

Disclaimer :  I truly believe this question has an objective answer, as I'm not asking which is best, just the main differences.

Comment: In answer to the question title: no, it causes a parse error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Studio is built on top of PDT, so it can do everything that PDT can do.  It happens that the Zend Studio site has a [feature comparison between it and PDT](http://www.zend.com/en/products/studio/comparison), showing where Studio's features are different.

Comment: yes, I have seen that comparison, but I am using both and there is no really big differences from them!! So why zend studio has a cost?

Answer (score 0):

Actually never, as Zend is pushing both products and one is commercial and one not. It will be a killer for ZendStudio to offer the same features as the PDT. Nevertheless PDT can be grown in features by the community, thus pushing Zend to improve more Zend Studio. And there is room for improvement...

Answer (score 0):

I started using Zend Studio early this year, and do not regret it one bit.  Zend Studio is specifically built for dealing with many different PHP-specific scenarios with all the features of Eclipse.  My favorite feature is the ability to refactor code, enabling users to rename (or move) a variable, class, class method, or function across the entire application.  Zend Studio also has great debugging capability including code tracing, full integration with Zend Server, tunneling, MySQL perspective, in-app PHPUnit code coverage, and much more.